# Select object from postgres function in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a function in postgresql that returns rows, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aaa.bbb(ss text, tt bigint DEFAULT NULL::bigint)
 RETURNS SETOF test.posts
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
    select * from test.posts where ss = $1 and tt = $2;
$function$
;
```

I have a model defined for test.posts but I don't know how to select Posts object from this function in python in sqlalchemy?

I was trying:

`session.query(Post).select_from(func.aaa.bbb(ss, tt)).first()`

but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did try to add schema? e.g. `db.session.query(func.schema.your_function())`

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a valid Postgres error message (and I doubt it's a valid Python error message either).

Comment: You use `select_from` to call function right?